# How can I use onoffline and ononline events in Chrome and other modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I see that `ononline` and `onoffline` events are [only available on Firefox and IE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onoffline.asp), but not for the other browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari). How could I set the events in Chrome and other modern browsers?

Comment: IE11 deprecates those events. That leaves just Firefox. They're probably going away and you should rely on other mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use navigator.onLine for all browser support as it is mentioned in link you provided. To whomever said that question is about checking if user is online - that's php's or what ever you prefer to use part not JS's.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bas van Dijk, I make it closer to perfection.

```
function setOnOffline(onOnline=function (){},onOffline=function (){}){
    window.online=onOnline;
    window.offline=onOffline;
    window.last123=navigator.onLine;registered
    setInterval(function (){
    if (!(window.last123==navigator.onLine)){
        if (navigator.onLine){
            window.online();
        }else{
            window.offline();
        }
        window.last123=navigator.onLine;
    }
    },1000/60);
}
```